# Dropdownlist reset after postpack when bound to function

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I have been having problems with dropdownlists in an asp.net project. After exhaustive checking I have narrowed things down to two scenario's. Before you respond please try this for yourself as proof. VS2010 or VS2012 ASP.Net project. I guarantee you this will NOT work.

I consider myself an experienced .net developer and code like this would normally be very trivial indeed for me but I am absolutely stumped with this one.

Any help would be appreciated

In my default.aspx **Page_Load** event page I have this code and nothing else

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
     cboDept1.DataSource = GetTeamGroups();
     cboDept1.DataValueField = "Value";
     cboDept1.DataTextField = "Text";
     cboDept1.DataBind();
}
```

With this version of the **GetTeamGroups** function code the dropdownlist works as expected, the list is preserved and I can get the **SelectedItem** etc. with no problems after each postback.

```
private List<ListItem> GetTeamGroups()
{
    List<ListItem> oList = new List<ListItem>();

    oList.Add(new ListItem("1", "1"));
    oList.Add(new ListItem("2", "2"));
    oList.Add(new ListItem("3", "3"));
    oList.Add(new ListItem("4", "4"));

    return oList;
}
```

Thats not practical where I want to get my list from a function (database, or webservice). But this version of the **GetTeamGroups** function this the dropdownlist is reset with each postback. I CANNOT get the SelectedItem. (PS. It doesn't really matter what code you use to dynamically fill the list, the problem is the same. Seems like the list cannot be filled dynamically for this to work).

```
private List<ListItem> GetTeamGroups()
{
    List<ListItem> oList = new List<ListItem>();

    string[] sGroups = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Groups"].ToString().Split(';');

    int iCount = 0;

    foreach (string sGroup in sGroups)
    {
        oList.Add(new ListItem(sGroup, iCount.ToString()));
    }

    return oList;
}
```

I have read numerous articles suggesting that the viewstate may help. No combination of viewstate on the control or page resolves the problem. The list is ALWAYS reset.

Comment: Try populating the dropdown list in the OnInit() method of the page.  You dont need to check for IsPostback() there and it should always be preserved IIRC.

Comment: @User Re read your code again you will find that causes this or debug line by line to page loads hopefully you will find it

Comment: How do you say that its getting reset?

Comment: Focus on your `ListItem`'s values, what do they look like when you bind dynamically?

Comment: When I say reset I mean repopulated, the selectedindex goes back to 0 and the selecteditem is back to the first one listed. I can never get the actual item selected. No errors or exceptions are generated.

Comment: OnInit also does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
New ListItem("Text","Value");
```

the value in the second function is repeated , you need to incremetn iCount into the foreach() loop,